# How to correctly instantiate the Iluminate class outside of laravel

Tags: validation, laravel, eloquent

I have Eloquent working outside of Laravel with no problems. Now Im trying to use also the Validation class by:

```
<?php

namespace User;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Validation\Validator;

class User extends Model {

    private $rules = array(
        'firstName' => 'required|min:2|max:50',
        'lastName'  => 'required|min:2|max:50',
    );

    public function validate($data)
    {
        $v = Validator::make($data, $this->rules);
        return $v->passes();
    }

}
```

Executing that code give me an error:

```
 Call to undefined method Illuminate\Validation\Validator::make()
```

That is correct since the method *make* is not on the class Validator but in his factory:
[image]

How can I correctly instantiate the Validation lib in order to get this working?

BTW, this is my composer.json:

```
{
    "require": {
        "slim/slim": "^2.6",
        "illuminate/database": "^5.1",
        "illuminate/validation": "^5.1"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "app/model"
        ]
    }

}
```

Comment: try using this `use Validator` instead of `use Illuminate\Validation\Validator`

Comment: @NehalHasnayeen PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Validator' not found in /var/www/test/app/model/user.php on line 18

Answer (score 5):

To get the validation package to work outside of Laravel, you'll also need the translation package.

So first create an instance of the translator, and then use that to make a validation factory.

### Working example

```
<?php

/*
Required composer packages:
    illuminate/validation
    illuminate/translation
*/

/*
Translation language files directory is the same as with Laravel
    ./lang/en/validation.php
*/

require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

// You need to specify where the translation files is
$test_translation_path = __DIR__.'/lang';
$test_translation_locale = 'en';

// Set up data for the validator
$test_input_data = ['field' => 'value'];
$test_input_rules = ['field' => 'required'];

$translation_file_loader = new Illuminate\Translation\FileLoader(new Illuminate\Filesystem\Filesystem, $test_translation_path);

$translator = new Illuminate\Translation\Translator($translation_file_loader, $test_translation_locale);

$validation_factory = new Illuminate\Validation\Factory($translator);

$validator = $validation_factory->make($test_input_data, $test_input_rules);

if ($validator->fails()) {
    die('Validation failed');
}

die('Validation passed!');
```

Comment: This is the correct answer for anyone who also wants the default messages.

Comment: This helped me to use validator to create validationException outside laravel or lumen!

Answer (score 4):

There are a few issues with your approach:

- you're trying to create a new `Validator` instance by calling the `Illuminate\Validation\Validator::make` method, yet you point out that the `make()` method is present on the `Illuminate\Validation\Factory` which is a different class altogether, so the error you're getting is justified.
- you're trying to call the `make()` method statically `::` when in fact it's not defined as such.
- you're trying to use the Validator the same as you would in a Laravel application enviroment, which won't work because you're missing the Laravel Facades and Service Providers infrastructure that Laravel uses to allow for such a simple instantiation of the Validator.

If you were to look at the `registerValidationFactory()` method inside the `Illuminate\Validation\ValidationServiceProvider` class, you'd get a sense of how the validator instance is created. So based on that, you could do the following:

```php
namespace User;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Validation\Factory as ValidatorFactory;
use Symfony\Component\Translation\Translator;

class User extends Model {

    private $rules = array(
        'firstName' => 'required|min:2|max:50',
        'lastName'  => 'required|min:2|max:50',
    );

    public function validate($data)
    {
        $factory = new ValidatorFactory(new Translator('en'));
        $v = $factory->make($data, $rules);

        return $v->passes();
    }

}
```

Comment: thank you!, this is working great, I see that you actually import the translator but how do you format/translate the error response. I add var_dump($v->messages()->all()); to the validate function in order to see the output when something fails, but im getting an string and not the translated phrase; array(1) { [0]=> string(21) "validation.min.string" } 

Do you know how to fix this?